# Import an external javascript library that is not listed in @types

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to use [this javascript library](https://github.com/Agezao/confetti-js) in my angular project, but I was not able to import it successfully.

---

The main file of the library is `dist/index.js`, and it has this one constructor definition:

```
window.ConfettiGenerator = function(params) {
//....
}
```

The problem that I am facing is when I am trying to import this library and use it in my component, I have the following error:

> ERROR TypeError:
>   confetti_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ConfettiGenerator is not a
>   constructor

---

This is how I am using the library:

```
import * as confettijs from "confetti-js";

//...

  ngOnInit() {
    let confettiSettings = {/* ... */};
    let confetti = new confettijs.ConfettiGenerator(confettiSettings);
    confetti.render();
  }
```

As this library is not part of the [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/npm) package, I am declaring it in `src/typings.d.ts` but with no success of being able to use it:

```
declare module 'confetti-js';
```

thank you for your help

Comment: It's saying that it's not a constructor, so don't use `new`.

Comment: I tried that but I ended up with the error that  it is not a function instead

Comment: Why not just use `let confetti = window.ConfettiGenerator(confettiSettings);`?

Comment: I just tried that but I had this error: `TypeError: cv.getContext is not a function`

Comment: So I went to the page you linked to, and it has instructions on how to do this. Have you tried simply following those?

Comment: Yes of course, I tried with the simple import `import "confetti-js";` and then calling the function with `new ConfettiGenerator(confettiSettings);` but I had the unknown constructor error

Comment: It turns out that the error `TypeError: cv.getContext is not a function` is relation to a bad configuration that I didn't notice. As you suggested, I used `new (<any> window).ConfettiGenerator(confettiSettings);` and it worked fine (I added the cast to `any` to avoid compilation errors). You can add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library exported via a global variable, so you can't import like your way. Try the following

- add library to scripts array in angular.json

  ```
  "scripts": [
            "node_modules/confetti-js/dist/index.min.js"
          ]
  ```
- component

  ```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  declare var ConfettiGenerator: any;
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
  })
  export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular';

    ngOnInit(){
      var confettiSettings = { target: 'my-canvas' };
      var confetti = new ConfettiGenerator(confettiSettings);
      confetti.render();
    }
  }
  ```